# What causes an 'AttributeGraph precondition failure' when using a TabView?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I had a single view application wrapped in a NavigationView where I populate data fetched from an API. However, I needed to add a profile section with a TabView and sometimes when I run the application, right when the launch screen is displayed, I get the following error (about once every three times I run/ debug the app) and the app crashes.

*AttributeGraph precondition failure: invalid value type for attribute: 56028 (expected PlatformItemList, saw BridgedTableViewState)*

The view that causes the error:

```
TabView {
    
    NavigationView {
        MainView()
    }
    .tabItem { VStack {
        Image(systemName: "list.dash")
        Text("main")
    }
    }
    
    NavigationView {
        ProfileView()
    }
    .tabItem { VStack {
        Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle")
        Text("profile")
    }
    }
}
```

I removed the TabView and the profile view and the app runs without any exceptions consistently, which is why I thought it was an issue with the TabView. I searched for documentation on AttributeGraph, PlatformItemList and BridgedTableViewState but found none.

Answer (score 0):

I had a related error: AttributeGraph precondition failure: invalid value type for attribute: 431640 (saw PreferenceKeys, expected ViewList).

This error did not arise in an app with almost identical functional and database code but using UIKit and manually-constructed tab view, list view etc. Only in the SwiftUI version with SwiftUI structs for these views.

Removing the Persistence class and persistence management seemed to resolve the issue (I use a direct SQLite coding for persistence instead of CoreData).

The Xcode error messages could be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I had experienced same problem. It was caused by combination of AnyView and NSViewRepresentable wrapper for WKWebView. Getting rid of AnyView by rewriting helper function with @ViewBuilder fixed the problem.

Problem:

```
func viewFunc() -> AnyView {
  switch self {
    case .case1: return AnyView(ListOfWebViewWrappers())
    default:     return AnyView(WaitView())
  }
}
```

Solution:

```
@ViewBuilder
func viewFunc() -> some View {
  switch self {
    case .case1: ListOfWebViewWrappers()
    default:     WaitView()
  }
}
```

the @ViewBuilder allows SwiftUI to properly track each view's identity and properly manage resources. More information about view's identity: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10022/

Answer (score -1):

I spent a lot of time dealing with precondition failure crashes in an app with multiple tab views. Is there any chance that one or more of your specific views (ProfileView or MainView) is also using a NavigationView? If so, that's probably the problem. Xcode will happily let you add NavigationViews in each new view, but it's not actually the way SwiftUI is meant to work. Since each TabView is wrapped in a NavView, then you shouldn't need/use a NavView inside of those views.

(Also, probably just cosmetic, but in the code snippet above there seems to be an extra close curly brace before your second Nav view.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But are you sure about it? I tried removing the NavigationView wrapping like you suggested, but I can't navigate anymore using navigation links. I also tried the debug view hierarchy and I don't see any navigation controller in the view stack... Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t mean to remove the NavigationView wrapping. My question was if the ProfileView or MainView ALSO included navigation views inside of them? If they don’t, then that wasn’t the problem. But if they do, then that seems a likely culprit. But my understanding is that wrapping those views the way you showed in your code is correct. The basic point is not to repeat NavigationView. If MainView is wrapped in a NavView, then it doesn’t need to declare another NavView inside of it. Maybe you could show the content of MainView.

Comment: No, they don't have NavigationView inside. Inside MainView is: VStack>List>NavigationLink>AnotherList

Comment: OK, multiple Nav Views is clearly not the problem then. Sorry, I can't solve the problem, but I can confirm for you that I had this same precondition failure crash and in my dozens of hours troubleshooting it, it clearly came down to the co-existence of Tab Views and Navigation Views making things unstable. Have you tried testing the same code in Xcode beta for iOS14? I found tab views much more stable in iOS14.

Comment: ok, i will have to experiment with different configurations of tab view then to close in on the issue. thanks for the effort

Comment: I have the same crash. but only have on NavigationView wrapping the TabBar. My crash _seems_ to be related to scroll view / geometry reader, but i cant be sure - super annoying / useless error message